# Add = or == to a base64 if necessary

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, base64

I am using the `Ionic Choose` plugin to take a file in an app, this one in the resolve returns me a base64 of the file I chose, the problem is that this base64 never ends with `=` or `==` when necessary in some cases.

When trying to send this base64 to the server it returns an error because the `=` or `==` is missing at the end of the string.

So I get the base64

```
this.chooser.getFile()
.then((file) => {

  let base64  = file.dataURI;

})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Can I somehow detect if base64 needs either `=` or `==` to complete the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base64 'blocks' consists of 4 characters, so if the final block contains less than 4 characters it gets padded with "=" sign, so it can have anywhere from 0 to 2 "=" signs in them, that's why the length of the dataURI needs to be a multiple of 4, You can do something like this:

```
  let base64  = file.dataURI;
  const len = base64.length;
  const modifiedBase64 = base64 + "=".repeat(len%4);
```